# Scala Summing Values of a list of Tuples in style (String,Int) based on _._1

Tags: list, scala, sum, tuples

I create a list of tuples via taking a String name and matching it to an accompanying int value.

I want to be able to sum those int values in the tuple in the case that there are multiple strings of the same name. My current approach follows this utilization of groupby which if I understand right is returning me a Map with keys based upon _ . _ 1 and list of values:

```
def mostPopular(data: List[List[String]]): (String, Int) = {
        //take the data and create a list[(String,Int)]
        val nameSums = data.map(x => x(1) -> x(2).toInt)
        //sum the values in _._2 based on same elements in _._1
        val grouped = nameSums.groupBy(_._1).foldLeft(0)(_+_._2)
}
```

I've seen other solution that have dealt with averaging different values of tuples but they haven't explained how to sum values that fall under the same name

Comment: Just in case it might be useful: https://github.com/reactormonk/scala-counter

Answer (score 4):

In your case `value` (see below code snippet) is a list of `(String, Int)` do `value.map(_._2).sum` or `value.foldLeft(0)((r, c) => r + (c._2))`

```
nameSums.groupBy(_._1).map { case (key, value) => key -> (value.map(_._2)).sum}
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val nameSums = List(("apple", 10), ("ball", 20), ("apple", 20), ("cat", 100))
nameSums: List[(String, Int)] = List((apple,10), (ball,20), (apple,20), (cat,100))

scala> nameSums.groupBy(_._1).map { case (key, value) => key -> (value.map(_._2)).sum}
res15: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(cat -> 100, apple -> 30, ball -> 20)
```